# What address should use to connect RestService?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I have a REST service which is running on **Tomcat** with address `localhost:8080/Pets/REST/WebService/GetFeeds`.

I want to use this URL on my Android app. What should I do to use it instead of **localhost**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out your ip address (with the ipconfig command on Windows), and replace localhost by that value.

Also, be sure that your android device is connected to the same network that your PC.

Comment: Connect it to the same network, configuring the Android device wi-fi.

Comment: Your android device has to "see" your PC in order to access the Tomcat app. That can happen if they are on the same network, or if your PC has a public address.

Comment: how can i know if pc has a public adress

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/117371/how-to-find-your-computers-private-public-ip-addresses/

Comment: i am running on a windows server is that mean it has a public adress ?

Comment: Read the article on the previous message. But most surely your PC does NOT have a public address. Therefore, you should connect your Android device to the same address than your PC.

Comment: PC has a public adress but i coulndt connect with using ip adress instead of localhost.

Comment: @KadirDiegoKılıc That is almost certainly because your PC doesn't have a public IP even if you think it has, or it's because there's a firewall on your PC, or elsewhere that stops you.